# Vue3 displaying list data loop warning Unhandled error during execution of render function

Tags: for-loop, graphql, vuejs3

I have Vue3 with apollo composable setup. I have for-loop data being displayed in a template that looks like this:

```
<template>
<div class="surface-card p-4 shadow-2 border-round w-full lg:w-8" style="margin:0 auto;">
    <ul class="list-none p-0 m-0 flex align-items-center font-medium mb-3">
        <li>
            <a class="text-500 no-underline line-height-3 cursor-pointer">Tab1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="px-2">
            <i class="pi pi-angle-right text-500 line-height-3"></i>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="text-900 line-height-3">Tab2</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="flex align-items-start flex-column lg:justify-content-between lg:flex-row">
        <div>
            <div class="flex font-medium text-3xl text-900">Client List</div>

        </div>
        <div class="mt-3 lg:mt-0">
            <Button label="Add" class="p-button-outlined mr-2" icon="pi pi-user-plus"  @click="openModal" />
        </div>

    </div>
<!-- for loop -->
    <p v-for="c in result.clients" :key="c.id">
        <b>{{ c.id}}</b>
    </p> 

</div>
</template>
```

There is no issues displaying the data and the code works but I get two errors in the browser:

```
[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of render function 
  at <ClientsList onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< undefined > > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <App> 
  at <App> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:38

[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of scheduler flush. This is likely a Vue internals bug. Please open an issue at https://new-issue.vuejs.org/?repo=vuejs/core 
  at <ClientsList onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< undefined > > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <App> 
  at <App> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:38
```

Commenting out the loop section of the code with the for loop makes the error disappear. The JavaScript in the .vue file looks like this:

```
import { getClients } from "@/graphql/query.js"
import { useQuery } from '@vue/apollo-composable'


export default {
    name: 'clients_list',
    setup(){
        const { result } = useQuery(getClients);
        return { result }
    },
```

Query data return to the variable result looks like this:

```
    {
      "data": {
        "clients": [
          {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Test1"
          },
          {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Test2"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

How do I get rid of the two warnings?

Comment: the warning suggests something happened during rendering so you need to post the rendering related code, i.e. your template

Comment: @Xinchao ok done it is only the loop part giving the warning. When I remove it the warning is gone too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not familiar with VueApollo, but that might be suggesting that at some rendering cycle some Ref value is `undefined` but used in rendering (`result.value`?).

After taking a quick look at VueApollo, I believe the `useQuery` method is asynchronous (merely based on the fact that it can also report loading status) - it returns you a `Ref` for holding the result but the data will not be available at a later time when the request completes. I cannot reproduce exactly the same warning message as it seems that you have other things in your setup. But if `result.value` is populated asynchronously, it will cause issue initially:

[example on Vue SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Try to guard against the `undefined` and see if it helps:

```
<p v-for="c in result?.clients" :key="c.id">
    <b> {{ c.id }} </b>
</p>
```